# JSS Import renderings into Shared Layout on Presentation Details

Tags: jss

When importing a Sitecore JSS App, we noticed that the default behavior is the renderings are added in the Final Layout in the Presentation Details in the item.

Is there a way to change the default behavior to have the renderings added to the Shared Layout instead of Final Layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible by turning off the `useLanguageSpecificLayout` setting on your JSS app definition.

`/sitecore/config/MyApp.config`:

```
<app name="MyApp"
  useLanguageSpecificLayout="false" />
```

[Example here](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/d0549adff90b09690be53940094afa6c45509d3d/samples/react/sitecore/config/JssReactWeb.config#L53)

Comment: Thank you for this. This is actually what we need.